# Unexpected "javascripts" tag in a twig template in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Why will encounter such mistakes remind?

[image: Code]
[image: Error]

Comment: Please move the external content as formatted code to your question.

Comment: DON"T use rude/abusive words. DON"T add screenshots of code, add actual code.

Comment: *how can I actually help this guy*

Comment: Just curious, is it *somehow* easier for you to take, upload, and link to an screenshot than simple copy-paste code? Because images of code aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{% javascripts %}` is a tag provided by AsseticBundle. Before using it, you must install and/or enable Assetic in your Symfony application. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html